# how to get selected element with the function getSelectedCurrency() in the folllowing code

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm building a currency converter app and I am trying to get the currency selected with the `getSelectedCurrency()` function in my code. When I console log value in my code it returns the text but doesn't satisfy TDD test of returning the selected currency

I've tried using an event listener but event listeners generally return undefined

```
 // declare populateCurrencies here      
   const populateCurrencies = ()=>{
    currencies.forEach((x)=>{
      let elt = document.querySelector('.select-text');
      let newElt = document.createElement('option');
      let newText = document.createTextNode(x.name);
      newElt.appendChild(newText);
      newElt.setAttribute('value',x.id);
      elt.appendChild(newElt);
    })
      let elt = document.querySelector('.select-text');
    elt.addEventListener('change',()=>{
       let currentlySelected =document.querySelector('[selected]');
       currentlySelected.removeAttribute('selected');
       elt.selectedOptions[0].setAttribute('selected','');
      },false)
    }

   function getSelectedCurrency(){
    // here, determine and return the selected value 
    // of the SELECT element
    let currentlySelected= document.querySelector('.select-text');
    let value= currentlySelected.selectedOptions[0].text;
    return((String(value)));
  };
  const convert = (event) => {
    toast(`preparing to convert ...`);

    const btn = event ? 
          event.target : document.querySelector('button');

    const selected = getSelectedCurrency();
    console.log(selected);

    if(!selected || selected.trim() === '' 
       || !currencies.map(c => c.id).includes(selected)) return;

    btn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    toast(`converting ...`);

    const endpoint = api(selected);
```

I expect `getSelectedCurrency()` to return a string but it returns nothing.

Comment: function getSelectedCurrency(){
        // here, determine and return the selected value 
        // of the SELECT element
        let currentlySelected= document.querySelector('.select-text');
        let value= currentlySelected.selectedOptions[0].textContent;
        console.log(value) ;
      };  returns undefined

Answer (score 0):

You were selecting the option in the wrong way

```js
function getSelectedCurrency(){
    // here, determine and return the selected value 
    // of the SELECT element
    let currentlySelected= document.querySelector('.select-text');
    let value= currentlySelected.options[currentlySelected.selectedIndex].textContent;
    if(value="")
    return false;
    else
    return value;
  };
```

Comment: returns undefined

Comment: @DamilolaOluwasusi Then either the `querySelector` is wrong or there is no selected option. Check if `currentlySelected` is the element you need, and also make sure that there is a selected option.

Comment: it worked but the problem is this: when i call startApp() which initiates the application the value of getSelectedCurrency() returns the default disabled select currency text.......                                                                                
   const startApp = () => {
        populateCurrencies();
        document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',(event)=>    {convert(event)},false);
      };
      startApp();